# JavaScript Execution Timeline

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on a project with a lot of code. When the page is fully loaded, a CSS class is removed by javascript. But I simply can't locate the line responsible for that, I am not even sure what javascript file contains that line.

Is there the possibility to see on a timeline what javascript function was called at a specific time?

When I use google chrome's devtools' "performance" tab, I can see that at the time when the CSS-class is removed, jQuery was fully loaded. But how can I see what line is responsible?

Alternatively, is there a way to see what javascript functions interacted with a DOM element?

Thanks!

Comment: "*a timeline what javascript function was called at a specific time*" - that's what the js profiler would do indeed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Chrome, you can use a DOM breakpoint to find this:

1. Right-click the element the class is removed from and choose **Inspect** from the menu. This opens the Elements panel with that element in view.
2. Right-click the element in the Elements panel and choose **Break on > attribute modifications**.

Reload the page (with devtools still open) and wait for the DOM breakpoint to be hit. It will switch to the Sources tab and highlight the statement removing the class.

Later when you want to remove the DOM breakpoint, you can find it on the Elements tab: In the pane on the right, choose **DOM Breakpoints** (you may need to use the **>>** button to see more choices, if the right-hand pane is narrow enough). It has a list of DOM breakpoints you can remove via a right-click menu.

Comment: Great answer. I also wasn't aware of this option.

Comment: That's a very neat feature, thanks.
It shows me, that jQuery's removeClass function removes the class.
Can I somehow find out what line initiates the call of removeClass?
Thanks!

Comment: @user1658080 - When it's stopped on the breakpoint, you should be able to see the current call stack on the right of the Sources tab under **Call Stack**.